# Node.js sequentially running multiple childProcess.execFile processes from q all

Tags: node.js, q

I am writing a program to batch print drawings. They need to be in a certain order ex. drawing A,B,C. The program plots the correct number of prints its just the order is random. I need the first in the array list to complete before next and so on.

```
    startMe(newPaths)
        .then(function(result){

        })

    function startMe(dwgPaths){
       return q.all(buildCalls(dwgPaths));
    }       
    var buildCalls = function(dwgPaths) {
        var calls = [];
        var scFiles = [tmpDir + "425011-fab.scr",tmpDir + "425011-pk.scr",tmpDir + "425011-sc.scr"];
        for (var sc in scFiles){
            for (var i in dwgPaths) {

                calls.push(callAccoreConsole(dwgPaths[i],scFiles[sc]));
            }
        }
        return calls;
    };
    function callAccoreConsole(dwgPath,scrFile){
        var deferred = q.defer();
        childProcess.execFile('C:/Program Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD 2015/accoreconsole.exe',['/i',dwgPath,'/s',scrFile], function(err, data) {
            if(err)
                deferred.resolve({success:false,reason: err});
            deferred.resolve({success:true});
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

The code below works the way I want. I print 2 files 3 copies each. File A using script 1,then File B using script 1. Then repeats for the other scripts. I have a total of 6 prints "three groups" A,B,A,B,A,B each with the appropriate script ran. With the code above I may get B,A,A,B,A,A.

```
                callAccoreConsole(newPaths[0],scFiles2[0])
                    .then(function(result){
                        callAccoreConsole(newPaths[1],scFiles2[0])
                            .then(function(result){
                                callAccoreConsole(newPaths[0],scFiles2[1])
                                    .then(function(result){
                                        callAccoreConsole(newPaths[1],scFiles2[1])
                                            .then(function(result){
                                                callAccoreConsole(newPaths[0],scFiles2[2])
                                                    .then(function(result){
                                                        callAccoreConsole(newPaths[1],scFiles2[2])
                                                            .then(function(result){

                                                            })
                                                    })
                                            })
                                    })
                            })
                    });
```

I have been struggling with this for a while. I found the code below and got it to work for my application, But it doesn't seem the most efficient way to be written. If any one has a more compact way let me know please.Thanks

```
          var itemsToProcess = [];
                for (var sc in scFiles){
                    for (var i in newPaths) {
                        itemsToProcess.push( {file:newPaths[i],script:scFiles[sc]});
                    }
                }
                function getDeferredResult(a) {
                    return (function (items) {
                        var deferred;

                        if (items.length === 0) {
                            return q.resolve(true);
                        }

                        deferred = q.defer();
                        var payload = {
                            file:items[0].file,
                            script:items[0].script
                        };
                        callAccoreConsole2(payload)
                            .then(function(result){
                                deferred.resolve(items.splice(1));
                            });
                        return deferred.promise.then(getDeferredResult);
                    }(a));
                }

                q.resolve(itemsToProcess)
                    .then(getDeferredResult)
                    .then(function(result){
                        return res.send({success:true});
                    })
```

Comment: Don't resolve promises to an error value; call `reject()` to reject the promise instead.

Comment: Or just use `q.nfcall()` to do all of this for you instead of defer.

Comment: So you don't want anything to run in parallel at all?

Comment: Can it be ran in parallel and in order?

Comment: @JamesMorris: What order do you care about if they are concurrent?

Comment: @JamesMorris: Those two terms literally have opposite meanings.

Comment: @SLaks your correct I wan't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

As you are constructing your array of promises you are simultaneously invoking the execFile method.

```
function callAccoreConsole(dwgPath,scrFile){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    childProcess.execFile('C:/Program Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD 2015/accoreconsole.exe',['/i',dwgPath,'/s',scrFile], function(err, data) {
        if(err)
            deferred.resolve({success:false,reason: err});
        deferred.resolve({success:true});
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

So, instead using `callAccoreConsole` to run the process and return a deffered, you need something that calls that method eventually -

```
calls.push(q.fcall(callAccoreConsole, dwgPaths[i],scFiles[sc]));
```

I haven't tried this specifically, but the gist is that you are calling your method at the same time you are creating the deferred for it.

Comment: Sorry. I am still new at this.Would I remove the promises from the callAccoreConsole function all together?

Comment: No, you would change where you are calling it and adding the deferred to the `calls` array to be like the line I provided.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I am still getting a random order of prints. I added more to my example above.

Comment: By using "calls.push(q.fcall(callAccoreConsole, dwgPaths[i],scFiles[sc]));" the call to execute the childProcess is delayed. But as I iterate the calls array of functions each function executes the process but it doesn't wait to to be resolved before the next is called.

Comment: Maybe the process you are invoking exits before the printing is done? Though I guess you say that it doesn't in your other example. It could also be how you are iterating over your list of file names using `for(var ... in ...)` instead of using `forEach` or `for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)` -- Any more information you could provide would be great.